# Using a dual rank memory in Asus X550LC Notebook

Tags: memory, motherboard

I would like to upgrade my Asus X550LC memory. Currently I have a 2 memory sticks of 4Gb each (one of the memory is soldered). I would like to replace the second memory stick (a M471b5173bh0-Yk0 Samsung 4Gb DDR3SODIMM 1600Mhz) with a one that with 8Gb. I am note sure if it is OK that I can add a Dual rank memory since the memory I have is a single rank. I searched on the internet to determine whether my motherboard support dual rank, but I did not find anything relevant.

Any comment or a suggestion is welcome
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

According to this you can upgrade to 12 GB max: https://www.memorystock.com/memory/ASUSX550LC.html

> How much memory does the ASUS X550LC Laptop take? You can upgrade your
> ASUS X550LC Laptop to up to a maximum memory capacity of 12GB Memory.
>
> How many total memory slots to install memory? The Laptop has 2 Slots
> (1 Upgradable) to install memory, already with 4GB (Soldered) standard
> memory installed. For best X550LC Laptop performance use the maximum
> amount of 12GB, fill all the slots with the max allowed memory per
> slot for your Laptop.

Also see https://www.manua.ls/asus/x550lc/manual?p=96